# Compilation Error related

Tags: java, static, static-methods

Given:

```
11. public static void test(String str) {
12. int check = 4;
13. if (check = str.length()) {
14. System.out.print(str.charAt(check -= 1) +", ");
15. } else {
16. System.out.print(str.charAt(0) + ", ");
17. }
18. }
and the invocation:
21. test("four");
22. test("tee");
23. test("to");
```

What is the result?

```
A. r, t, t,
B. r, e, o,
C. Compilation fails.
D. An exception is thrown at runtime.
Answer: C
```

Can you explain why the compilation fails please?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (check = str.length())
```

The expression in the above `if` is an assignment which is equivalent to: -

```
if (str.length())
```

So, the expression is evaluated to an `integer` value. 
Which is a compilation error. Since an expression in `if` statement should evaluate to a `boolean` value in `Java`.

So, the `if` statement should be written as: -

```
if (check == str.length())
```

in order to successfully compile.

Answer (score 1):

Compilation error is because of this `check = str.length()` statement inside `if` i.e. `if (check = str.length())`. **Its assignment and not comparison.** `If` statement expects final evaluation to be an `boolean`.

The correct statement would be as below with comparison `==` operator:

```
           if (check == str.length())
```

Answer (score 1):

line 13 should be as follows

```
if (check == str.length()) {
```